# Which stack exchange site would be ok to ask this question- What are the processors in machines

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I come across one doubt

Someone telling me *assuming you had a 4 processor machine*. Obviously this is about computer only but where can I ask this question like what is processor or are they coming built in laptops etc..

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose the problem here is that a minimal amount of research would tell you the answer, whether it's in terms of sockets, physical processors, physical cores or logical cores.

It's not really going to be well received and is likely to be voted down in it's current form. You're better off looking at system documentation, wikipedia and Google first and if your answer isn't found there, then maybe ask a question.

Comment: Literally I do not have time to google. I thought stack exchange would be a good option to get doubts clear. Moreover I have got few more doubts like processors related to i4 or i5 or 4ghz or 5ghz. So it doesn't seem invalid question. Ultimately I need to know _Where to ask this my question_ but you ended up telling something else. Thank you

Comment: There's literally no difference between asking a question in a Google text box and here. Actually Google is faster. There's no such thing as an i4 thought....

Comment: I'd have to agree with Journeyman Geek here - this type of question is faster on Google than SE. It really is the minimum level of research. SE is more useful when you have tried google and others but they don't hold the info you need, or it requires multiple searches, analysis, correlation etc

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Anyway! Thank you for giving answer what you wanted to give. Yeah there is no i4 :)

Comment: 5 Ghz and 4 GHz i5's don't exist either.

Comment: @Arvindraja The general rule is “if you don’t have time to google, you certainly don’t have time to ask on SE”. This is because background googling is a prerequisite needed before you ask any question on any site in SE. you should never use SE as a substitute for googling.

Comment: @DanBron - Thank you for your input. :)